# Can't find qpython on the playstore

Tags: android, google-play-services, qpython, qpython3

I can't find qpython in the playstore anymore. If it's removed, is there another way to get it. I tried the link on the qpython website but this goes to a playstore page that says the article doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qpython changed its app ID from com.hipipal.qpyplus to org.qpython.qpy.

That's why they made it offline then online again.

You can download it here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.qpython.qpy ☺

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be gone from the play store but you can always google `QPython apk` to get the previous version. [APK4FUN](https://www.apk4fun.com/apk/1455/)

Answer (score 1):

QPython 3 APK Repo: https://github.com/qpython-android/qpython3/releases.

Make sure you're allowed to install APKs (unknown sources).

**EDIT:** You can get the older release of QPython 1.2.5 from [this GitHub Repo](https://github.com/qpython-android/qpython/releases), and that is also an APK file so it can be installed the same way as QPython 3, just make sure you can install applications from unknown sources. However, there's no real reason to install such an old version.

Also if you want some more info on QPython, they do have a [website, qpython.com](http://qpython.com/), where there is an [extensive wiki with documentation and support](http://wiki.qpython.org/doc/).